# Why does my second menu in the Wordpress dashboard not display?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, dashboard

I've created two menus for the Wordpress dashboard and the first one functions as it should but the second one doesn't appear. I'm not sure why.

**Here is my code :**

```
// Programme 2015 CPT
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Programme 2015 HP', 'Post Type General Name', 'test' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Programme 2015 HP', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'test' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Programme 2015 HP', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'test' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Tous les blocs programme 2015 en HP', 'test' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Voir le Programme 2015', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Ajouter un bloc au Programme 2015 en HP', 'test' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Ajouter', 'test' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editer', 'test' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Mettre à jour', 'test' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Chercher', 'test' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'test' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'test' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'programme-2015', 'test' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Les blocs programme dans la HP', 'test' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-media-text',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'programme-2015', $args );

// Editions précédentes HP 

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Editions précédentes', 'Post Type General Name', 'test' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Editions précédentes', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'test' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Editions précédentes', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'test' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Toutes les éditions précédentes', 'test' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Voir une édition précédente', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Ajouter une année précédente', 'test' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Ajouter', 'test' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editer', 'test' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Mettre à jour', 'test' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Chercher', 'test' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'test' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'test' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'editions-precedentes-hp', 'test' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Les blocs éditions précédentes en HP', 'test' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-microphone',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'editions-precedentes-hp', $args );
}

"// Hook into the 'init' action

add_action( 'init', 'jm_custom_post_type', 0 );"
```

Could anyone shed a light on my problem?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't appear? Where are you calling it? Have you assigned items to it in the Admin? Have you assigned the menu in the admin?

Comment: It doesn't appear into the dashboard admin menu on the left side under the one i've created "Programme 2015 HP" which appear.This array is called by the functions.php file with this : include 'inc/post-type.php'; Where can i assign items and menu in the admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editions-precedentes-hp` is too long, it can be **20 characters max.**